# How to navigate from one route to another route in ReactJS

Tags: reactjs, react-router

Ive been trying to develop a Web App using react and react-router-dom where the user clicks on a button on of my react routes. I would ideally like the user to be navigated to completely new page after clicking said button.

For reference I have a landing page where I have react router allow the user to switch between either a sign in or sign up form to be displayed on the page

```
<Router>
  <NavLink to="/sign-in" activeClassName="FormTitle__Link--Active" className="FormTitle__Link" > 
  Sign In </NavLink>
   or
  <NavLink exact to="/sign-up" activeClassName="FormTitle__Link--Active" 
  className="FormTitle__Link" > Sign Up </NavLink>

  <Route exact path="/" component={signUpForm}></Route> 
  <Route path="/sign-in" component={signInForm}></Route>
<Router>
```

^Ive left out some of my code but just left the parts regarding react-router

There are buttons on both sign in and sign up pages and I would like to figure out some way, either using react-router or any other method to be able to navigate from these routes as I attempted to use react router again inside of my signUpForm/signInForm files but soon found out you cannot use  within a route.

Let me know if I need to clarify anything or provide more information.
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

If your `signUpForm` and `signInForm` components are properly defined and imported in the provided file the only thing you need now is to put these `<Route .../>` elements inside `<Switch/>` component. I think something like this would help:

```
<Router>
  <NavLink to="/sign-in" activeClassName="FormTitle__Link--Active" 
    className="FormTitle__Link" > Sign In </NavLink>
   or
  <NavLink exact to="/sign-up" activeClassName="FormTitle__Link--Active" 
  className="FormTitle__Link" > Sign Up </NavLink>
 <Switch>
   <Route exact path="/" component={signUpForm}/> 
   <Route path="/sign-in" component={signInForm}/>
 </Switch>
<Router>
```

Comment: How exactly would <Switch> allow me to navigate from one of my routes without causing any issues? What would the code look like within the route components such as signInForm or signUpForm? Thanks in advance

Comment: `<Switch>` component is a part of `react-router-dom` that's how its going to work. For more descriptive explanation you could check out this https://reacttraining.com/react-router/web/guides/quick-start